# Creating a checkered board with pieces in HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I am experimenting with canvas in HTML and JS and attempting to draw a canvas of a chess board with 16 pieces on each side of it. I was able to create the chess board but am stuck on how I would draw just specifically the 16 pieces on each side (The pieces can just be circles so just one side with 16 red circles, one side with 16 blue circles).

I don't know why this is so confusing to me, I know you probably just need a for loop stopping at the specific coordinates but to get different colored pieces on each side as well as stopping at certain part is giving me trouble.

I would just like assistance on where in my code would I be placing the chess pieces in. If you could just modify my current code and place comments on where you made the changes so I could see then that would be very appreciated.

Here is what I have so far to make the checkers board:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>

function drawCheckeredBackground(can, nRow, nCol) {
    var ctx = can.getContext("2d");
    var w = can.width;
    var h = can.height;

    nRow = nRow || 8;    
    nCol = nCol || 8;   

    w /= nCol;            
    h /= nRow;            

    for (var i = 0; i < nRow; ++i) {
        for (var j = 0, col = nCol / 2; j < col; ++j) {
            ctx.rect(2 * j * w + (i % 2 ? 0 : w), i * h, w, h);
        }
    }

    ctx.fill();
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

drawCheckeredBackground(canvas);
```

Here is how I want the chess board to look like, with 16 pieces on each side like so. I just quickly made this example in paint:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iy1bB.png

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the most beautiful solution possible, but it should offer some basic ideas and is adjustable using your `step` variable idea. Chances are, you'll need to refactor when going for actual pieces.

```js
const drawBoard = (ctx, step) => {
  for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
      ctx.fillStyle = (i + j) & 1 ? "black" : "white";
      ctx.fillRect(j * step, i * step, step, step);
    }
  }
};

const drawPieces = (ctx, y, color, step) => {
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  
  for (let i = y; i < 2 * step + y; i += step) {
    for (let j = step / 2; j < 8 * step; j += step) {
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(j, i - step / 2, step / 3, 0, Math.PI * 2);
      ctx.fill();
    }
  }
};

const step = 60;
const c = document.createElement("canvas");
c.height = c.width = step * 8;
document.body.appendChild(c);
const ctx = c.getContext("2d");

drawBoard(ctx, step);
drawPieces(ctx, step, "red", step);
drawPieces(ctx, step * 7, "blue", step);
```

[Play with it at JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dxmj8kzL/9/).

Comment: ctx.arc can be used to draw multiple circles in the same path. It'd be better to put beginPath before the loop & fill after it's done.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. It'd also be better to precompute inner loop computations and the math can be simplified I'm sure. I'm not trying to write ultra performant code, though; this is just a simple sketch to demonstrate the approach. The board drawing routine is called twice, so it seems premature to start optimizing.

Answer (score -1):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
   body {
    background-color: black;
   }
   
   canvas {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
    border: solid 1px white;
    border-radius: 10px;
   }
  </style>
 </head>
 
 <body>
  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <script type="application/javascript">
  
  // Self executing function
  void function() {
  
   // Turn on strict js rules for this scope
   "use strict";
   
   // Classes
   
   function ChessPeice(x,y,radius) {
    this.x = x || 0.0;
    this.y = y || 0.0;
    this.radius = radius || 1.0;
   }
   
   ChessPeice.prototype = {
    tick: function() {
    
    },
    
    render: function(ctx) {
     ctx.moveTo(
      this.x + this.radius,
      this.y
     );
    
     ctx.arc(
      this.x,
      this.y,
      this.radius,
      0.0,
      2.0 * Math.PI,
      false
     );
    }
   };
   
   // Constructor, when called with 'new' creates an object and puts it
   // in the 'this' variable, new properties can then be added to it.
   function Chessboard(width,height) {
    this.boardWidth = width || 1;
    this.boardHeight = height || 1;
    this.tileWidth = this.boardWidth / this.H_TILE_COUNT;
    this.tileHeight = this.boardHeight / this.V_TILE_COUNT;
    this.whitePeices = [];
    this.blackPeices = [];
    
    for (var y = 0; y < 2; ++y) {
     for (var x = 0; x < this.V_TILE_COUNT; ++x) {
      this.whitePeices.push(
       new ChessPeice(
        x * this.tileWidth + (this.tileWidth >> 1),
        y * this.tileHeight + (this.tileHeight >> 1),
        this.CHESS_PIECE_RADIUS
       )
      );
      
      this.blackPeices.push(
       new ChessPeice(
        x * this.tileWidth + (this.tileWidth >> 1),
        (this.V_TILE_COUNT - 1 - y) * this.tileHeight + (this.tileHeight >> 1),
        this.CHESS_PIECE_RADIUS
       )
      );
     }
    }
   }
   
   // Prototype object, all objects created with 'new Chessboard()'
   // will share the properties in the prototype, use it for constant values
   // & class functions
   Chessboard.prototype = {
    H_TILE_COUNT: 8, // How many white & black tiles per axis?
    V_TILE_COUNT: 8,
    
    EDGE_THICKNESS: 10.0,
    EDGE_COLOUR: "#603E11FF",
    WHITE_TILE_COLOUR: "#BBBBBBFF",
    BLACK_TILE_COLOUR: "#555555FF",
    
    CHESS_PIECE_RADIUS: 5.0,
    WHITE_PIECE_COLOUR: "#EEEEEEFF",
    BLACK_PIECE_COLOUR: "#333333FF",
    
    tick: function() {
     // You can add game logic here
    },
    
    render: function(ctx) {
     // Draw white tiles
     var x = 0;
     var y = 0;
     var totalTiles = this.H_TILE_COUNT * this.V_TILE_COUNT;
     
     ctx.fillStyle = this.WHITE_TILE_COLOUR;
     ctx.beginPath();
     
     for (var i = 0; i < totalTiles; ++i) {
      ctx.rect(
       x * this.tileWidth,
       y * this.tileHeight,
       this.tileWidth,
       this.tileHeight
      );
      
      x += 2;
      
      if (x >= this.H_TILE_COUNT) {
       x = this.H_TILE_COUNT - x + 1;
       ++y;
      }
     }
     
     ctx.fill();
     
     // Draw black tiles
     x = 1;
     y = 0;
     
     ctx.fillStyle = this.BLACK_TILE_COLOUR;
     ctx.beginPath();
     
     for (var i = 0; i < totalTiles; ++i) {
      ctx.rect(
       x * this.tileWidth,
       y * this.tileHeight,
       this.tileWidth,
       this.tileHeight
      );
      
      x += 2;
      
      if (x >= this.H_TILE_COUNT) {
       x = this.H_TILE_COUNT - x + 1;
       ++y;
      }
     }
     
     ctx.fill();
     
     // Draw edge
     ctx.lineWidth = this.EDGE_THICKNESS >> 1;
     ctx.strokeStyle = this.EDGE_COLOUR;
     ctx.beginPath();
     ctx.rect(0,0,this.boardWidth,this.boardHeight);
     ctx.stroke();
     
     // Draw white pieces
     ctx.lineWidth = 2;
     ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000FF";
     ctx.fillStyle = this.WHITE_PIECE_COLOUR;
     ctx.beginPath();
     
     for (var i = 0; i < this.whitePeices.length; ++i) {
      this.whitePeices[i].render(ctx);
     }
     
     ctx.fill();
     ctx.stroke();
     
     // Draw black pieces
     ctx.lineWidth = 2;
     ctx.strokeStyle = "#000000FF";
     ctx.fillStyle = this.BLACK_PIECE_COLOUR;
     ctx.beginPath();
     
     for (var i = 0; i < this.blackPeices.length; ++i) {
      this.blackPeices[i].render(ctx);
     }
     
     ctx.fill();
     ctx.stroke();
    }
   };
   
   // Variables
   var canvasWidth = 160;
   var canvasHeight = 160;
   var canvas = null;
   var ctx = null;
   var board = null;
   
   // Game Loop
   function loop() {
    // Tick (Update game logic)
    board.tick();
    
    // Render
    ctx.fillStyle = "gray";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);
    
    board.render(ctx);
    
    //
    requestAnimationFrame(loop);
   }
   
   // Entry Point (Runs when the page loads)
   onload = function() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    canvas.width = canvasWidth;
    canvas.height = canvasHeight;
    
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    board = new Chessboard(canvasWidth,canvasHeight);
    
    loop();
   }
  
  }();
  
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```